# Scala 2.11 -> 2.12 -- Unit test fails in sbt, works in IntelliJ

Tags: java, scala, unit-testing, intellij-idea

I have a project that has been working under Scala 2.11, and I'm in the process of upgrading it to use Scala 2.12. I've got a unit test that fails when I run it on the command line through sbt, but it works fine when I run it through IntelliJ IDEA.

The error I get is:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: scala.Product.$init$(Lscala/Product;)V
```

The test is a JUnit test in Java, and it invokes code written in Scala.

The offending line in the unit test:

```
String paramsJson = adapter.sendReadyMessage();
```

The `sendReadyMessage` method (also Java) attempts to create a `ReadyMessage`:

```
ReadyMessage rm = new ReadyMessage(timestamp);
```

And a `ReadyMessage` is just a Scala case class

```
case class ReadyMessage(Timestamp: String) extends ToJson
```

And `ToJson` is a lift-JSON helper trait that encapsulates JSON generation:

```
import net.liftweb.json.{DefaultFormats, Serialization}

trait ToJson {
  private implicit val formats = DefaultFormats
  def toJson = Serialization.write(this)
}
```

The error appears to happen on the `case class ReadyMessage` line. The `ToJson` block is there for context.

Like I said, it works when I run it from within IntelliJ. It fails when I run it under sbt. It fails when it's part of the whole batch of tests in sbt, and it fails when I run it on its own in sbt.

Short of pasting my entire build.sbt file, I'm not sure what other information to include here that might be useful. It seems like it's some kind of version conflict, but I went through and updated all of the software version numbers I can find.

I realize this question covers an issue that may be more complex than can be reasonably debugged over SO. But even a "make sure you've updated XX in your build.sbt" response is helpful.

Comment: You can always try to cut it down until you get a small reproducible example. Otherwise, here are some more or less random suggestions: 1) check that all the library dependecies are intended to work with scala 2.12 (just as an example: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.spark/spark-core it differentiates between 2.10 and 2.11, and has no version that is built for 2.12 at all, and it is not reflected in the version number in the sbt). 2) Could you add the setting `fork := true` to the sbt, and see whether anything changes? 3) check scalaVersion is set properly.

Comment: `java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: scala.Product.$init$(Lscala/Product;)V` I have seen this message when my app was missing Scala 2.12 runtime library in the class path. SBT should take care of this, though.

Comment: It happens when fork is set to true or false. And now it appears to be happening in both sbt and IntelliJ.

Comment: I copy/pasted the command line from a working run from IDEA, and now it fails.

Comment: Do you have a library dependency that's still compiled against an old Scala version?

Comment: What's with this weird sbt-intellij interaction going on there? Just save everything, close everything, `sbt clean` everything you can, kill all java processes, clean all caches that could possibly have gone stale, check again that all libraries are suitable for 2.12, make sure that the `java` (on which sbt itself relies) is up to date and compatible with the requirements of your libraries (some might require 1.7 or 1.8 specifically), set `scalaVersion` in the `build.sbt` properly, set `fork := true`, issue `sbt compile` from the console. What happens?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer turned out to be as annoying as the problem itself.

After many hours of searching my build, I realized that there was a "lib" directory in the subproject that was failing. I opened it up, and sure enough, it contained old versions of Scala and some other libs. I deleted those, made sure the libraryDependencies took care of them, and now everything builds and tests just fine.

Thanks to everyone for keeping me on board the "it's a Scala version mismatch" train. And let this be a cautionary tale, kids. Mix your managed and unmanaged dependencies at your own peril.